# What are client methods in Java?

Tags: java, terminology

I'm relatively new to Java and trying to learn more about the terminology. As I was reading, I came across the term `client methods` in a discussion about public, private and static variables.

Here are a two questions that I have regarding this term:

- Are `client methods` simply all methods that are not declared within a specific file? Say I have two files, one called `File1.java` and the other `File2.java`. If `File2.java` contained a method called `printText`, would that be considered a `client method` from the perspective of `File1`?
- Why are they called "`client`" methods, what exactly defines a client? Are there `client variables` too?

**Edit:** As a reference, I saw this term in the current latest edition of the [Barron's AP Computer Science A book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1438005946), here is a direct quote:

> The variable OVERDRAWN_PENALTY is an example in the BankAccount class.
>   Since the variable is public, it can be used in any client method. [...]  A
>   client method would refer to the variable as
>   BankAccount.OVERDRAWN_PENALTY. In its own class it is referred to as
>   simply OVERDRAWN_PENALTY.

**Re-Edit**, this part was included a bit before the quote above:

> Similarly public methods are accessible to all client programs.
>   Clients, however, are not privy to the class implementation and may
>   not access the private instance variables and private methods of the
>   class.

Comment: as far as i know there is no such thing as `client methods` in java

Comment: *What* were you reading? It's not a standard term that I'm aware of...

Comment: Can you quote what you've read? I don't know of the term "client method" in Java's context, nor does Google, really.

Comment: Perhaps they meant the client code, like in code that uses the library and calls the API, from the API's (library's) perspective? Just a guess, though.

Comment: My question has been edited to include the reference.

Comment: I never heard of "client methods". I'm pretty sure there is no such terminology in Java. Maybe the book sucks.

Comment: @Tiny I am required to use this book as a study tool for my course. Good to know that this term doesn't exist and I didn't just skip over something though.

Comment: The term "client" for users of an API (e.g. a method) is quite common to me. So if it's a method that uses another method the first one is a client to the latter. I cannot answer offhand from which books I learned this terminology. It's completely unrelated to "network clients" in this context.

Comment: @Tiny could you please explain? Based on context, I assume that "client programs" means other files in directory that have access to this method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, based on your comments this section of the book seems to use the term `client methods` as a short version of "methods not in this class/package/library that use this class".

Comment: Although this is the shortest answer, I think this accurately depicts what the book is trying to say, so I'll accept it as an answer for reference.

Answer (score 1):

I think it just means "exposed to a client". Think about an API, it can contain any number of methods of various visibility modifiers, but the only ones you can directly use as a "client" are those that are `public`.

After reading that a few times, though, it does seem to say a method not within the same class that accesses the current class is considered a "client method".

Answer (score 1):

The word "client" is typically used to connote "a user of some other system or service."

When one speaks of a *client process*, for example, this is meant to indicate a process that accesses, uses, or consumes services that are provided by some corresponding *server program or process*.

This language has carried over, more generally, into discussions of APIs.  A "client" of an API is a program (often written by a different programmer) that accesses the services that are defined by the contract of that API.  As an aside, in Java an API is formed by all the members of the classes and interfaces which can be accessed by classes in different packages (i.e. the *exported members* define the API).

In the paragraph provided:

> The variable OVERDRAWN_PENALTY is an example in the BankAccount class.
>   Since the variable is public, it can be used in any client method.
>   [...] A client method would refer to the variable as
>   BankAccount.OVERDRAWN_PENALTY. In its own class it is referred to as
>   simply OVERDRAWN_PENALTY.

The *client method* refers to a method (probably written by someone else) that accesses the services of the `BankAccount` class, in this case the public variable in the class.

Answer (score 1):

The term "client" for users of an API (e.g. a method) is quite common to me. So if it's a method that uses another method the first one is a client to the latter.

It's completely unrelated to "network clients" in this context.

One – rather authoritative – source for this is the book "Effective Java" by Joshua Bloch.

Let me quote two examples:

> The normal way for a class to allow a client to obtain an instance of itself is to provide a public constructor.

and:

> In short, the telescoping constructor pattern works, but it is hard to write
>   client code when there are many parameters, and harder still to read it.

You may easily come up with "client method" then I think.